# Drawing text at boundary of another text object in Matplotlib

Tags: python, text, matplotlib

I'm trying to create text labels on a graph in Matplotlib, and I'd like to highlight certain words using a different colour. Since Matplotlib doesn't have a native feature to do this, I figure I could position two text elements next to each other, but I'm having trouble aligning them properly.

I found [this suggested code](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/697#issuecomment-3859591) for a relevant feature request, and the sample output below it is what I want to emulate, but I'm unable to replicate it, even if I copy the code he used and save it to a PNG ([this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/66eUb.png) is what I get). Did Matplotlib change how its API handles translation or getting text boundaries?

How can I accomplish this? Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the code you linked to works fine with a small modification. It's an excellent example to what you want to do, so I am not posting any real new code, just my modified version:

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import transforms

```
def rainbow_text(x,y,ls,lc,**kw):
    """
    Take a list of strings ``ls`` and colors ``lc`` and place them next to each
    other, with text ls[i] being shown in color lc[i].

    This example shows how to do both vertical and horizontal text, and will
    pass all keyword arguments to plt.text, so you can set the font size,
    family, etc.
    """
    t = plt.gca().transData
    fig = plt.gcf()

    #### note: this line moved down ....### 
    #plt.show()                           #
    #######################################
    #horizontal version
    for s,c in zip(ls,lc):
        text = plt.text(x,y," "+s+" ",color=c, transform=t, **kw)
        text.draw(fig.canvas.get_renderer())
        ex = text.get_window_extent()
        t = transforms.offset_copy(text._transform, x=ex.width, units='dots')

    #vertical version
    for s,c in zip(ls,lc):
        text = plt.text(x,y," "+s+" ",color=c, transform=t,
                rotation=90,va='bottom',ha='center',**kw)
        text.draw(fig.canvas.get_renderer())
        ex = text.get_window_extent()
        t = transforms.offset_copy(text._transform, y=ex.height, units='dots')

    t = plt.gca().transData
    fig = plt.gcf()
    plt.show() ############### when this is here, you can see that 
               ############### all unicorns poo rainbows ;-)

plt.figure()

rainbow_text(0.0,0.0,"all unicorns poop rainbows ! ! !".split(), 
        ['red', 'orange', 'brown', 'green', 'blue', 'purple', 'black'],
        size=30)
### worked on matplotlib version 1.1.0 on Debian Wheezy. Which version did you try?
```

Comment: I tried to run this code, but I get a similar result where the words overlap each other. Can you try doing `plt.savefig('filename')` and seeing if the PNG comes out correctly as well? I'm trying to use this feature within the matplotlib source code, I am using a build from the latest clone from their GitHub. I can try to install the packaged version and see if it helps.  Is there anything else that could not be set up properly that might cause this?

Comment: It seems that there is something wrong in the png backend. Also in my case. I tried saving the image as PDF, and it's working better. Try playing a little bit with the width and hight (x=ex.width*0.9 would change where the vertical text starts. You could also change y=ex.height*1.1 so it fits better. Note also when you make a pdf, you could specify the size of your PDF with (figprops = dict(figsize=(10, 10)) # this is 10 inches by 10 inches...but it works damn good with the huge font.
fig = plt.figure(**figprops). Try this and let me know what you get.

Comment: It seems to be working after I change the backend to WXAgg/GTKAgg. The only problem is that when I try to use segments like "this word is " and "red", it bundles them as "this word isred" in some cases, perhaps due to the trailing whitespace in the first phrase. If I transfer that whitespace to the next phrase, it works perfect. Thanks!

Comment: Hey once again. I just noticed the PNGs still don't work. Looks like it's not getting the correct extents with that renderer or not translating properly... I guess that's the first thing to look into.

Comment: Hey, me once again! Woohoo! I actually figured it out; the backends were fine, and it's actually a problem with `offset_copy`. I noticed that the `get_window_extent` function is supposed to return it in the figure units, so I was wondering if 'dots' should instead be 'points'. However, trying this, the spacing was too much, so I went into the `offset_copy` function definition and noticed that it was hard-coded to divide by 72 as opposed to getting the DPI from `fig.dpi`. After doing that, the separation works perfectly in the interactive and PNG versions! I should commit this change, perhaps!

Comment: Hmm, apparently 'points' is 72 DPI by definition, so that wasn't it. Curious that it works perfectly, though.

Answer (score 0):

I was playing around with your code for my own purposes and thought I would just add what I've done here.

This example is a modification of your code that allows for any text angle rotation. However this only works for text `va='bottom'` and `ha='left'`.

```
import math
import numpy

from numpy.linalg import inv
from matplotlib import transforms
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def rainbow_text(x, y, ls, lc, theta, **kwargs):
    fig = plt.gcf()
    axis = plt.gca()

    theta_rad = math.radians(theta)
    text_trans = axis.transData
    for s, c in zip(ls, lc):
        text = plt.text(x, y, " %s " %s,
                        verticalalignment='bottom',
                        horizontalalignment='left',
                        color=c,
                        transform=text_trans,
                        rotation=theta,
                        **kwargs)

        text.draw(axis.figure.canvas.get_renderer())

        # solve for the text width and height
        bbox = text.get_window_extent(axis.figure.canvas.get_renderer())
        theta_mat = numpy.array([[math.cos(theta_rad), math.sin(theta_rad)],
                                 [math.sin(theta_rad), math.cos(theta_rad)]])
        txt_size = numpy.dot(inv(theta_mat),
                             numpy.array([bbox.width, bbox.height]))

        # plot the bounds for each word (only works with axis autoscaling off)
        for i in range(4):
            bounds = bbox.corners()
            point = axis.transData.inverted().transform(bounds[i])
            plt.plot(point[0], point[1], '*', color=c)

        x_offset = txt_size[0] * math.cos(theta_rad)
        y_offset = txt_size[0] * math.sin(theta_rad)
        text_trans = transforms.offset_copy(text.get_transform(),
                                            fig=fig,
                                            x=x_offset,
                                            y=y_offset,
                                            units='points')


plt.figure()
plt.axis([0, 5, 0, 5])

rainbow_text(1, 1, "all unicorns poop rainbows ! ! !".split(),
             ['red', 'orange', 'brown', 'green', 'blue', 'purple', 'black'],
             20, size=20)
plt.savefig('blarg.png', ext='png')
plt.show()
```